# Authentication problems with pymongo and flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mlab

I am trying to connect with pymongo and flask. I did this:

```
app.config['MONGO_HOST'] = 'ds02XX.mongolab.com'
app.config['MONGO_PORT'] = '29224'
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'myusername'
app.config['MONGO_USERNAME'] = 'myusername'
app.config['MONGO_PASSWORD'] = 'thislongpasswordthatigotfrommongolab'
```

However, when I call `mongo=PyMongo(app)`, it simply does not work. and I get this error:

```
pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: command SON([('authenticate', 1), ('user', u'myusername'), ('nonce', u'somenumbers'), ('key', u'othernumbers')]) failed: auth failed
```

Is there anything I could do to check? I used the same data to connect via mongo shell, and it worked fine!

Thanks,

Francis

Comment: what versions of mongodb and pymongo?

Comment: I am using heroku and mongolab, so i don't know exactly which version is ran by mongolab. However, my requirements.txt are as follow:Flask==0.10.1
Flask-PyMongo==0.3.1
Flask-RESTful==0.3.4
Jinja2==2.7.3
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.9.6
aniso8601==0.82
gunicorn==19.0.0
itsdangerous==0.24
pymongo==3.0.3
pytz==2014.4
six==1.7.2

Comment: It works locally, but not on heroku - somehow i fixed it locally.

Comment: I am getting the exact same issue.  It was working fine up until mongolab rolled out updates last week to their sandbox MongoDB instances.  Now I cannot connect with the pymmongo driver, but I can still connect with the mongo shell.  It must be an issue only affecting certain mongolab instances.  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, PyMongo 3.0.3 is not working. They - Mongolab - said that the drivers should be compatible with MongoDB 3.0, and PyMongo 3.0.3 is. 
I reverted back to PyMongo 2.8 and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message while using: MongoDB 2.6 and PyMongo 3.2. Tried downgrading my PyMongo to versiones 2.7 and 2.8, but was not working. Finally I got to connect successfully by updating my connection string to include the database.

Changed from:

```
'mongodb://'+ MONGODB[ 'username' ] + ':' + MONGODB[ 'password' ] + '@' + MONGODB['server'] + ':' + MONGODB['port'] + '/'
```

to

```
'mongodb://'+ MONGODB[ 'username' ] + ':' + MONGODB[ 'password' ] + '@' + MONGODB['server'] + ':' + MONGODB['port'] + '/' + MONGODB['database']
```

MongoDB version 2.6 requires the connection strings to include the database if using credentials. If database is not included, then the mongo client will try to authenticate and connect to a default admin database. It is detailed [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/connection-string/).